# QGIS Shortest Path Iteration

Tags: qgis, algorithm, iteration, shortest-path

I have a large QGIS Fiber to the Home (FTTH) design with 727 address, my focus here is on the Lateral sections from the homes to the Handholes (shown in green).
[image]

The design roughly breaks up to four homes per handhole (Clusters) and I would like to get the paths from the homes in the respective Cluster to the respective Handhole.  I can easily do this once or twice using the Shortest path (layer to point) alogrithm as shown below.  The problem is that I have 175 of these clusters
[image]

Looking for some input for how to approach this programmatically.  Are there some other path algorithms beyond the 'Shortest Path' series of functions?  v.net.path looks like it may have some potential

Comment: Depending on how your data is structured you should just be able to use Shortest path (layer to point) in Batch Processing mode.